# can't run shell script outside its directory

Tags: centos, shell, centos5

I am centos 5.4 user and I can't run shell script outside its directry i.e my script is located:

```
/me/script.sh
```

it will run as

```
./script.sh
```

but not as

```
/me/script.sh
```

it is 755 chmod, why its like that ?

cheers,
/Marcin

Comment: What is the error message you get when you run /me/script.sh ?

Comment: nothing, just really does nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What error does it give you?

Did you write it to be run from anywhere, or inside it does it call programs by relative path such as 'program' instead of '/me/program' and it now cannot find them?

Comment: its just echo program, really dummy stuff for testing purposes, then there is no dependencies at all

Comment: OK, got it, as you said, I have realized that I am running something what requires proper path, anyway, all fixed.

Comment: This anser helped me after 11 years.

Answer (score 0):

Run your shell script as `bash -x /me/script.sh` and see what's going wrong.  There's no overall technical reason a script can't work outside your directory, so it's got to be something you're running that expects `$CWD` to be `/me`.